# Linking to images referenced in vuex store in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url-routing, vuex

I am using Vue.js for the first time so apologies if this is a basic question – I have set up the vue project with the **vue-cli**, **vue-router** and **vuex** if this information is helpful.

My main issue here is with displaying images or accessing assets. I am able to pull the appropriate data/state in from a data store via a 'getter' and iterate arrays, etc within it (for example, `{{student.name}}` works perfectly) however when I attempt to display an image with `<img :src='student.image'>` it fails to load and I get a broken link icon. I've done some research and it seems that there is a webpack naming convention for linking assets with `~/` or `~@/` however neither of these seem to work.

I've seen other examples where people simply link to a fixed asset from the component but because I am iterating the `students` array I need a more programmatic method. I've seen some examples using `computed()` properties but I feel like this should be unnecessary?

Below is the code from my component and the relevant parts of my `store.js` file.

Store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {
      score: 0
    },
    students: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Advik',
        age: '19',
        studying: 'Physiotherapy',
        image: '~/assets/images/students/advik-1.png'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jake',
        age: '19',
        studying: 'Drama',
        image: '~/assets/images/students/jake-1.png'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Mel',
        age: '20',
        studying: 'Civil Engineering',
        image: '~/assets/images/students/mel-1.png'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Kaya',
        age: '18',
        studying: 'Law',
        image: '~/assets/images/students/kaya-1.png'
      }
    ]
  },
  mutations: {

  },
  methods: {

  },
  getters: {
    getStudents: state => state.students
  },
  actions: {

  }
})
```

Intros component:

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <div class="m-background"></div>
    <Brand />
    <div class="l-container">
      <div v-for="student in getStudents"
           :key="student.id">
           <img :src='student.image'>
           <router-link class="m-btn m-btn--left m-btn__primary"
            :to="{ name: 'home' }">{{ student.name }}
           </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import Brand from '../../components/Brand'

export default {
  components: {
    Brand
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getStudents'])
  },
  name: 'Intros'
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:src='student.image'` (v-binding) is executed at runtime, but webpack aliases work in compile time. So you have to wrap the aliased file path in `require`.

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Advik',
  age: '19',
  studying: 'Physiotherapy',
  image: require('~@/assets/images/students/advik-1.png')
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jns! Do you also happen to know how I would link to a directory one folder up the file tree? My `store.js` file is in a 'store' folder at the same level as 'assets'? I've tried variations on `../` such as `require('~@../assets/images/students/advik-1.png')` but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I feel like there must be something else I am doing wrong @Jns, now I get a failed to compile error which is good, but it says: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~@/store/advik-1.png' in /my-project/src/store'
 @ ./src/store/store.js 18:13-44
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js`

Comment: Could you create a small fiddle at codesandbox.io, which has a simliar structure as your project, please?

Comment: If your file is just in the top-level `assets` folder, you don't want the `~` -- just use `require("@/assets/.../whatever.png")`

Comment: Hi both @DanielBeck and @Jns – thanks for your help – my assets folder was in the top level so the straightforward `@` has worked a treat, thank you! I wonder if either of you know of a website that has documentation on this? I can't find a _reason_ why this naming convention is the case? Why the `~` and/or the `@`?

Comment: The vue-cli docs explain it a bit (though not thoroughly or well imho): https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules