# getting images url in vuex store in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, image, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using vuex in nuxt and I get user data after user login, and store the data in vuex.

When I display the data in another page as computed property with getters, everything works fine and it displays user data except for img tag.

When I try to display user icon with url which is stored in vuex, it works for the first time, but when refresh the page, it gets the data before the user data is stored for some reason...( but the another data still renders user data properly) and of course, icon does not render.
Plus, if I just display the url of icon from vuex as strings in div, it shows icon url correctly even after refreshing the page... but not src in img tag...

I think I have a same problem as this question: [Linking to images referenced in vuex store in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412106/linking-to-images-referenced-in-vuex-store-in-vue-js)
and one of the answer says

> **:src='student.image' (v-binding) is executed at runtime, but webpack aliases work in compile time. So you have to wrap the aliased file path in require.**

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Advik',
  age: '19',
  studying: 'Physiotherapy',
  image: require('~@/assets/images/students/advik-1.png')
}
```

so, I would like to use require in src but icon is rendered by url not by module, so I do not know how to solve this problem. How can I make icon render after refreshing the page as well?

This is my vuex,

```
//---------this is default state data--------------
export const state = () => ({
  user: {
    email: 'default',
    id: 'default',
    last_name: 'default',
    name: 'name',
    picture: 'picture',
    provider: 'default',
  },
}
// -------this is to set user and token in store and local storage-------
export const mutations = {
  setUser(state, authData) {
    const now = new Date()
    const expirationDate = now.getTime() + 36000000
    localStorage.setItem('token', authData.token)
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(authData.user))
    localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate)
    state.idToken = authData.token
    state.user = authData.user
  },
}
//---------this is to get userdata and fire mutation to set data ---------
export const actions = {
  GetUserInfo({ commit }, token) {
    this.$axios
      .get('/auth/user/', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        const user = {
          email: res.data.email,
          id: res.data.id,
          last_name: res.data.last_name,
          name: res.data.name,
          picture: res.data.picture,
          provider: res.data.provider,
        }
        return user
      })
      .then((user) => {
        commit('setUser', { token, user })
      })
  },
}
```

and this is index.vue where I am trying to display the user info.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ userAvatar }}</div>    //this displays picture url first time and after refreshes it as well. 
    <img class="avatar" :src="userAvatar" alt="" />    //this displays icon with picture url first time and, after I refresh it, userAvatar renders as "picture" which was the default data of state.
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  computed: {
    userAvatar() {
      const user = this.$store.getters['authentication/getUserInfo']
      console.log(user) //even after refresh it, still console the user data I got.
      return user.picture 
    },
  },
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to set `user.picture` as `false` for default, then on your img tag add `v-if="userAvatar"`. or just use a loader set loader false when your app storing data to vuex and set it true when finish storing the data and use `v-if` on your component

Comment: Hi! I tried, but unfortunately it did not work... Thanks for your help tho!