# how to have external link in require() in <img> tag src

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the exact same problem as this question: [Linking to images referenced in vuex store in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412106/linking-to-images-referenced-in-vuex-store-in-vue-js)

However, unlike the question, I have external link for src of  tag such as 'https://....'.

Is there any way I can put the link in require()?
I know it has only the path but I need something like require() that runs in compile time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you expect from using `require()` with full URL? Because it doesn't make sense at all...

Comment: Yes, I know but when I try just src="...." it does not get my data that is stored in vuex, other data that is displayed in div tag work fine. but vuex state data in img tag is not working. that's why I am asking if there is any similar way as require that I can get image with the external link....

Comment: `require` has nothing to do with Vuex. You should probably update you question with some relevant code...

Comment: Please check the link I put in the question.  The best answer says "src='student.image' (v-binding) is executed at runtime, but webpack aliases work in compile time. So you have to wrap the aliased file path in require." and I have the exact same problem, that's why I am asking because v-binding src in img tag is executing before getting my vuex data.. I have the same question with code as well, so please check it if you can help. Thank you anyway tho.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem, i solved it as follows, i'm not sure of how this affects speed and prerendering and dist, but it worked for me, the img from an external URL is shown in dev mode. hope this helps, i know it's not what you're looking for in sense of require('URL'), but for me it's a workaround i can live with

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="imgURL" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imgURL: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // on mounted, create the string of your URL and asign it to a variable in data
    this.imgURL = baseURL+dynamicURL
  }
}
</script>
```